# Image classification with Neural Network in R

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, r, image-classification

I want to classify images in a few different groups with a Neural Network algorithm in R. I have tried different things but nothing works. So my question is: what is the best way to read in images so that I can put the data in a Neural Network algorithm?

Check out my other question as well for things that I have tried already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660306/picture-classification-with-neural-network-in-r

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but I would strongly suggest branching into a different language like Python to attempt these kind of tasks, neural networks and specifically convolutional neural networks have a very strong support in a language like Python and very limited in R

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use R, loading images can be done with imager. General information, tutorials and case studies can be found [here](http://dahtah.github.io/imager/).

As for neural networks in R, the basic ones which are available like nnet, RSNNS and deepnet are to probably too slow. I recommend looking into H2O for deeplearning. If you want to go with GPU support you need to look at other options, like tensorflow or mxnet.

Tensorflow in R: You can use tensorflow from R with the tensorflow package. Information on how to install and use it from R can be found [here](https://rstudio.github.io/tensorflow/) .

MXNET in R: follow the instructions from the [mxnet github page](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/R-package).